# Is it okay to use the words "awesome" and "amazing" as adverbs like in "The Lakers played amazing/awesome tonight"

Tags: word-usage

On dictionaries(for instance, definitions of [awesome](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/awesome) and [amazing](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amazing) on Cambridge Dictionary), there are no definitions of "awesome" or "amazing" as adverbs (they are only defined as adjectives), but I think native English speakers can use them as adverbs. So I wonder if it is wrong usage because you can't find any adverb definitions of them. For example, is it wrong to say,

- **"The Lakers played amazing tonight"** to mean **"The Lakers played in an amazing way/extremely well tonight"**;

and is it wrong to say,

- **"The Lakers played awesome tonight"** to mean **"The Lakers played in an awesome way/extremely well tonight"**?

And another question is, if those two words can be used as adverbs, why isn't this specified on dictionaries?

Context: The Lakers are a famous basketball team.

Comment: The syntactic principle is the same whichever of ***good, awesome, confident*** you include in your utterance (as opposed to ***well, awesomely, confidently***). But whereas using ***good*** instead of ***well*** here isn't particularly uncommon, using ***confident*** instead of ***confidently*** would be quite unlikely. ***Awesome*** instead of ***awesomely*** falls somewhere between those two extremes of "acceptability" - but if you want to be "right", stick to true adverbs.

Answer (score 3):

No, those are adjectives. You could turn them into adverbs and say they played "amazingly" or "awesomely".
Another possibility is to use the words as adjectives: "They played an amazing/awesome game."
You may hear some native speakers use those adjectives as adverbs, but they will sound uneducated to many of us.

Comment: We get tired of hearing 'awesome' all the damn time. Alternatives are a good thing.